# Facebook FQL: Get Userevents with Latitude and Longitude unter iOS

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I'm desperately trying to get the Userevents with Latitude and Longitude. I'm using right now this query but it returns an empty resultset and I have no clue why.

```
NSString *eventInfo = @"SELECT name, eid, venue.id, location, start_time, end_time from event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() AND rsvp_status='attending' OR rsvp_status='maybe'))";

NSString *placeInfo = @"SELECT page_id, name, latitude, longitude FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT venue.id FROM #event)";

NSDictionary *multiQuery = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys: eventInfo, @"event", placeInfo, @"place", nil];

NSDictionary *queryParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: multiQuery, @"q", accessToken, @"access_token", nil];
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you don't need second query: all info that you need about venue you can receive in 1st query, `venue` is a complex object with name and coordinates.

So, when you run the query

```
SELECT name, eid, venue, location, start_time, end_time from event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me() and  rsvp_status='attending' OR rsvp_status='maybe')
```

you should get all venue information in `venue` array.

Comment: I already tried this kind of query out. Unfortunately Facebook returns just the ID for the Venue and not more. Despite the fact that they wrote in the documentation that it inherits all those attributes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the query to do this:

```
{
    "events" : "SELECT privacy, name, description, start_time, venue.id, pic_cover FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me())",
    "venues" : "SELECT latitude, longitude, name, page_id FROM place WHERE page_id IN (SELECT  venue.id FROM #events)"
}
```

Note that you need to do the join manually, with objective-c. All facebook can gives us is a list of events, and a list of venues related to the events.

Answer (score 0):

try this query it will return pretty much every thing about the up coming event

```
SELECT eid,name,description,venue,creator,location,ticket_uri,start_time, eid,host,not_replied_count,pic_square,pic_big,unsure_count,attending_count,declined_count,all_members_count FROM event WHERE eid IN ( SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid = me()) AND start_time > now(
```